# Error when creating cluster environment for azureML: "Failed to get scoring front-end info"

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I just started with using the Azure Machine Learning Services and ran into this problem. Creating a local environment and deploying my model to localhost works perfectly fine. 
Can anyone identify what could have caused this error, because i do not know where to start..

I tried to create a cluster for Location "eastus2" aswell, which caused the same error.
Thank you very much in advance!

Btw, the ressource group and ressources are being created into my azure account.

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYwJD.png)

Comment: Btw I was following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/preview/deployment-setup-configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ashvin [MSFT]

Sorry to hear that you were facing issues. We checked logs on our side using the info you provided in the screenshot. The cluster setup failed because there weren't enough cores to fit AzureML and system components in the cluster. You specified agent-vm-size of D1v2 which has 1 CPU core. By default we create 2 agents so total cores were 2. To resolve, can you please try creating a new cluster without specifying agent size? Then AzureML will create 2 agents of D3v2 which is 8 cores total. This should fit the AzureML and system components and leave some room for you to deploy your services.

If you wish a bigger cluster you could specify agent-count along with agent-vm-size to appropriately size your cluster but please have minimum total of 8 cores with each individual VM >= 2 cores to ensure cluster works smoothly. Hope this helps.

We are working on our side to add error handling to ensure request fails with clear error message.